# Database mirroring for report database

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

I have a problem that our production database is under heavy load.
So we have decide that we setup a second SQL server running copy of production database that doesn't need to be 100% uptodate with production database.

After searching I have found that asynchronous mirroring of production database might do the trick.
Mirror database would be only read-only for reports and stuff.
So I managed to set it up, but have found out that I can't read any data from mirror database because it is in recovery mode.

No I would like to know if my problem is solvable with mirroring or we should use alternative?

Comment: Simon I think that with simple mirroring database will not be readable. You can use Transactional Replication. I think you can also use AlwaysOn Availability Groups if you use 2012 and above but I do not have any experiance with that

Comment: Thanks. So replications or AlwaysOn Availability groups would do the trick?

Comment: I use merge replication for the same reason as you but yeah I think Availability Groups will do too. See this on [dba exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53815/clustering-vs-transactional-replication-vs-availability-groups)

Comment: error: transactional replication not merge

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Blim, we have decided for transaction replication. It works great on our development database (so it should in production too).

Step by step article: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2010/transactional-replication-2008-r2/